# How to use psd-tools with python

Tags: python, parsing, psd

I am trying to parse psd files and I found these tool [Psd-Tools](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools).
Just so you know, I am new into the python environment.

I have followed the following steps and everything went well:

```
pip install psd-tools
pip install docopt
pip install Pillow
pip install packbits
```

I can see them when I write `pip freeze`. But I can't see any of these `modules` in python with this command:

```
>>> help('modules')
```

Obviously, when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
>>> from psd_tools import PSDImage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psd_tools
```

I have python-2.7.3 and python3-3.3.0 installed on my mac. Whether I launch `python` or `python3`, none of them find the `psd_tools` module.

So my guess was that the module has a different name, but none of these seems to work `"psd-tools"` `'psd-tools'` `psd\-tools`.

Maybe I missed a step with `pip`? Or the module name has changed, then how can I see it ?
Did anyone already use [Psd-Tools](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools)?

Comment: Can you try do download source code and install it manually?

Comment: Thank you man, I didn't even think I could that. So I just cloned the [Psd-Tools repo](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools) and used this command `sudo python setup.py install`. You should post this as an answer with the previous command and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use install it from the source, from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools) of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do `python --version` and `pip --version` to see what version of Python each of them are using. It's possible one or both are not what you expect.

FWIW, `pip install psd-tools` then `import psd_tools` worked fine for me on OSX on 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right, if pip version matches python version.